# Button on Floatlayout is Not working while executing code in kivy

Tags: android, python, cross-platform, kivy, kivy-language

I have two buttons on floatlayout both has on_press() event

```
    Button:
        id: button1
        size_hint: .12,.12
        pos_hint:{"center_x":.30,"center_y":.065}
        on_press: root.speeak(textbox2.text)
    Button:
        id: button2
        size_hint: .12,.12
        #pos_hint:{"center_x":.50,"center_y":.065}
        on_press: root.stop()
```

Method behind the buttons

```
 def speeak(self,texts):
    self.texts = texts
    global speak
    speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
    speak.Speak(self.texts)

def stop(self,*args):
    speak.Pause()
```

When I press button1 whole layout hang and stop button not work. Someone has any Idea for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the code blocks at `speak.Speak(self.texts)` and you won't be able to pause or do anything until that line is done. One way of solving this is to use [`multithreading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and use a thread to run `speak.Speak(self.texts)` so your main loop doesn't get affected. Here is an example you can start with:

```
import threading

def speeak(self, texts):
    self.texts = texts
    self.speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.speakStart, args=(self.texts,))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

def speakStart(self, text):
    self.speak.Speak(text)

def stop(self):
    self.speak.Pause()
```